# use variable to specify format in python

Tags: python

I want to format a string to a fixed width

If I use the following statement:

```
"{0:<8}".format(str(size)) #This one works
```

However,

```
# This one gives Invalid conversion specification
"{0:<width}".format(str(size))
```

Is there anyway to use a variable to format a string?

Comment: You could chain multiple formats together, but that would be ugly. Another way would be to just append to a string, or use one of the other ways to string format in addition to this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solution 1:
Use `width` to generate a string `{0:<8}` first

```
width = 8
("{0:<%d}"%width).format(s)
```

Solution 2:
Nested `format`:

```
"{0:<{1}}".format(s, width)
```

Named format maybe more readable:

```
"{string:<{width}}".format(string=s, width=width)
```

Solution 3:
Another way to translate `{0:<8}`: `.ljust(8)`

```
"{0}".format(s.ljust(width))
```

I choose `3.` when
1) dealing with other encodings in i18n
2) print pretty

```
print 'a'.rjust(10, '-')
---------a
```

Answer (score 2):

It needs the actual value, not the string `'width'`.

```
str(width).join(("{0:<", "}")).format(str(size))
```